# Разобраться с Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Есть приложение на 2ух языках (англ и русский) с google maps и на карте есть 2 строчки:

1. В ней определяется почти точное местоположение телефона (адрес)
2. В неё можно вписать другой адрес

Суть проблемы:

Карта отображается на той локале что выбрано (т.е. если русский в телефоне то и всё на карте по русски) НО вот 2 строчки выше описанные выдают адреса только на англ языке.

Подскажите что и где смотреть?

[image: Скриншот с телефона]

Comment: желательно код какой-то добавить, и скриншот проблемы тоже не помешает, а то так на пальцах сложно понять в чем проблема)

Comment: Я даже не знаю какой кусок кода Вам прислать) Мне сказали что мол проблема в файле CustomGooglePlacesSearch

Comment: ну вы с картами работаете, вот покажите как именно, так же покажите скрин где языки криво сетятся

Comment: Я тут недавно и не вижу как прикрепить файл с кодам, он на 1000 строк почти

Comment: файл крепить не нужно, и 1000 строк никто тут смотреть не будет, просто нет скриншота, нет кода который возможно является причиной проблемы, и человек зайдет прочитает, и чисто гипотетически что-то посоветует, но будет сложно) хотя-бы скриншот прикрепите того что у вас не работает так как нужно)

Comment: Понял Вас, попробую отредактировать вопрос с добавлю скриншот.

Comment: если перед созданием карты в активности добавить такую строку `Locale.setDefault(new Locale("ru"));` что-нибудь поменяется?

Comment: Нет не получается. Пробовал. Но сама же карта на русском. А адреса по англ все

Comment: Возможно вам поможет это руководство Гугл https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/localization

Comment: К сожалению не чего не выходит) Есть у кого еще мысли какие-нибудь?